# How do I add a column with a repeating series of values to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like a add a column with a repeating series values to a dataframe with the each value in the list being repeated a set number of times, for example:

```
   x   y  z
   0   2  1
   2  15  1
   0  10  2
   2  20  2
   0  30  3
   2  50  3
```

Where each value in z is repeated twice.

So far I have this which repeats the whole list rather than each item in the list a set number of times:

```
data = [[0, 2], [2, 15], [0, 10], [2, 20], [0, 30], [2, 50]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x', 'y'])

df1['z']=0
np.put(df1['z'], np.arange(len(df1)), [1, 2])
print(df1)
```

Result:

```
x   y  z
0   2  1
2  15  2
0  10  3
2  20  1
0  30  2
2  50  3
```

How can specifiy the number of times to repeat each item in the list rather than repeating the whole list? Also, Ideally it would be great if the solution could be applied to strings as well as integers, many thanks!

Comment: `df1['z'] = np.tile(np.arange(len(df1)), 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question but:

using list comprehension

```
ntimes = 2 # number of times you repeat each item
yourlist = [1,2,3]
df1['z'] = [i for i in yourlist for _ in range(ntimes)]
```

does what you're looking for.

```
   x   y  z
0  0   2  1
1  2  15  1
2  0  10  2
3  2  20  2
4  0  30  3
5  2  50  3
```

Comment: any idea why I get ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (64776) when I try this code as is? I am trying to get the same 3 values to keep repeating over and over (as in row 1 "X", row 2 "y", row 3 "z", row 4 "X", row 5 "y", row 6 "z", etc etc?